# How add vertical line to bar char in d3js?

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I´m noob using d3js I´m trying add a new vertical on Basic Horizontal Bar Chart of d3js. To test I´m using codepen but the vertical line is not shown.

HTML file

```
<head>
  <!-- Plotly.js -->
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
 <script>
  <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE -->
 </script>
</body>
```

JS file

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [20],
  y: ['giraffes'],
  name: 'SF Zoo',
  orientation: 'h',
  marker: {
    color: 'rgba(55,128,191,0.6)',
    width: 1
 },
 type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  title: 'Colored Bar Chart',
  barmode: 'stack'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 400]);
var svg = d3.select(document.getElementById('myDiv'));
svg.append("line")
.attr("x1", 10)
.attr("y1", y(0))
.attr("x2", 10)
.attr("y2", y(1))
.style("stroke", "black");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `svg` variable is a HTML `<div>` element:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
//"myDiv" is the ID of the div

var svg = d3.select(document.getElementById('myDiv'));
//you're getting the div here -----------------^
```

However, you cannot append a SVG line to a HTML div.

**Solution**: select the svg itself:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
```

Now your `svg` variable points to the SVG, in which you can append a SVG line.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var trace1 = {
  x: [20],
  y: ['giraffes'],
  name: 'SF Zoo',
  orientation: 'h',
  marker: {
    color: 'rgba(55,128,191,0.6)',
    width: 1
 },
 type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  title: 'Colored Bar Chart',
  barmode: 'stack'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 400]);
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.append("line")
.attr("x1", 10)
.attr("y1", y(0))
.attr("x2", 10)
.attr("y2", y(1))
.style("stroke", "black");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
```

PS: You don't need `getElementById` in a D3 code. To select that div, for instance, just do `d3.select("#myDiv")`.